# When using a '&' next to the return type, are you returning a reference, or is it a bit-by-bit copy still?

Tags: c++

When using a '&' next to the return type, are you returning a reference, or is it a bit-by-bit copy still?

Example:

```
T& operator[](const int index)
{
    return m_array[index];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no copy made of m_array[index] - the return is a reference variable to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are never "returning a reference". This is a general sloppiness of expression by people who hopefully know better, but if you're new or unsure, it pays to be accurate: What really happens is that *evaluating a function produces a value*. Values have types, and those types are always object types (i.e. never references). So a function cannot "return a reference"; a function always "returns a value", if you will. (But it's better to say that "function evaluation produces a value".)

The only question is what that value is. If a function is declared as `U f()`, where `U` is an object type, then the value is a temporary, which is passed around by copy (at least nominally). However, if the function is declared as `U & f()` or `U && f()`, then the value *is* some existing object, and no new object is created and passed around. Such function evaluation lets you see some existing object directly, if you will. Colloquially we say that "`f` returns a reference", but be careful with such language.

In your case, `m_array` is an existing object, `m_array[index]` is (presumably) some subobject of that object, and the function evaluation produces that very object (which is presumably some array element).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the terms "returning a reference" and "return by reference" are commonly used by prominent authors (examples I found on my bookshelf - Bjarne Stroustrup, Scott Meyers, Herb Sutter).

Comment: @JBentley: It's a convenient shorthand if you know what you're talking about. Do you think it's a helpful expression for the new learner? (And funnily enough, the accepted answer is just plain wrong.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps your answer could be expanded upon. I've re-read it a few times now, and I'm not clear on why one must "be careful with such language". What is the difference between a function which "lets you see some existing object directly", and a reference?

Comment: @KerrekSB: not the downvoter either, but re "helpful expression for new learner" - yes... returning a reference *to an object* is IMHO easier for a learner to grasp that asying "the function evaluation produces that very object" which makes it sound like a by-value return, that a const reference thereto could extend the lifetime etc..

Comment: @JBentley: A reference is kind of type (a "compound type"). A function is a function. Since they're different things, it's useful to keep them separate mentally. The key mechanic in C++ is that expressions bind to references, which is hard to get right if you start out confused (`decltype(auto)` anyone?).

Comment: Ok, but (and I'm not trying to be pendantic, I'm trying to understand what you're saying)... if a reference is a kind of type, and a function returns an object of a given type, then why can it not return a reference, in the same sense that it can return an int (for example)?

Comment: @JBentley: Values are never references, that's why. Values *bind* to references, and references must always be *variables*. Not all values are variables, and not all variables are values (but variables can be *evaluated* to produce values).

Comment: a reference is a pointer with object semantic. the function returns just that

Comment: @sp2danny: if I could downvote comments ;-P.  I'm sure we all understand where you're coming from, but there's so much wrong with that assertion it's not funny.

Answer (score 0):

> When using a '&' next to the return type, are you returning a reference, or is it a bit-by-bit copy still?

You are returning a reference to whatever object the function's `return` statement specifies (so that shouldn't be a temporary, which the leading `m_` implies it's not - all good).

Still, returning references to objects is not the opposite of "bit-by-bit copy"... C++ often uses custom copy constructors and/or assignment operators to ensure proper deep copying etc..